# MySQL query that checks in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with two `mysql` tables. I've done some code and I think I am close to the solution, but I'm not sure if this is right.

So here are the two tables:

```
Table 1: Blogs
Columns: ID, agp_name, agp_url, agp_username, agp_password

Table 2: Keywords
Columns: ID, agp_user_id, agp_order_id, agp_blog_id, agp_keywords, agp_keywords_date
```

What I want is to get one random row from Table1 based on the following condition: if the `agp_keyword` match one of the keywords in the last 5 days then do not include into the result.

So far I did this:

```
SELECT 
t1.agp_user_id, t1.agp_order_id, t1.agp_blog_id, t1.agp_keywords, t1.agp_keywords_date, t2.agp_name, t2.agp_url, t2.agp_username, t2.agp_password
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT ID, agp_name, agp_url, agp_username, agp_password, agp_blogposts 
  FROM table2 
) AS t2 ON t1.agp_blog_id = t2.ID 
WHERE
  t1.agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%keyword1%" AND 
  t1.agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%keyword2%" AND 
  t1.agp_keywords_date BETWEEN (1369440000 AND 1369932432) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

However this does not work correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is table2 table 1 in your schema?

Comment: and can your make more clear what is not working correctly, what result do you expect and wich result do you get

Comment: Hi Miguelo
The problem is that if there is nothing in keywords table for the particular blog then this is not returning it.

Comment: then the answer below might help you, an inner join will return only the rows that can be joined. A left join will return all rows  the from the left (t1) table based on the where condition. So try the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your original specifications were a bit confusing :(

```
SELECT keywords.agp_user_id, 
       keywords.agp_order_id, 
       keywords.agp_blog_id, 
       keywords.agp_keywords, 
       keywords.agp_keywords_date, 
       blogs.agp_name, 
       blogs.agp_url, 
       blogs.agp_username, 
       blogs.agp_password
FROM blogs 
LEFT JOIN keywords
    ON keywords.agp_blog_id = blogs.ID 
        AND keywords.agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%keyword1%" 
        AND keywords.agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%keyword2%" 
        AND FROM_UNIXTIME(keywords.agp_keywords_date) > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAYS))
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Updated the answer slightly, replaced `t1` and `t2` to the respective tables, and moved some of the code around

Comment: Well I think I've forgot to mention - is it possible that it will get result from blogs even if there is nothing in keywords for the particular blog?

Comment: It can do, if you replace `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Hi Phil. This works fine when I comment out WHERE clause. Is it possible to return the result when either there is no agp_keywords_date or if not in last 5 days?

Comment: @DeyanKostadinov I've edited the SQL in my answer. I've changed it from an `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` to return a blog entry, even if there aren't any keywords. In addition, I've removed the `WHERE` clause and moved it into the `join` condition. This should hopefully work as you want :)

Comment: Hi Phil, I am sorry to bother you again. Can you please check:
http://deyhost.com/mysql.jpg
This is what I have in the tables.
What I want is: if there are is a keyword within the 5 day period to return the random of the other two blogs.

The keywords table represents which keyword is added when and I would like to prevent adding the same keyword to that blog within 5 day period.